# What does "activity without action" mean?

Tags: terminology

In 1804, poet Robert Southey said of Coleridge:

> His mind is in a perpetual St. Vitus dance—eternal activity without
>   action.

In *The Inconvenience of Being Born*, the Romanian philosopher Emil Cioran mistakenly reported these words as said by Wordsworth, and added:

> It seems to me that everything one does is pernicious and, at best,
>   useless. Strictly speaking, I am only allowed to fidget not to act. Now I understand all too well Wordsworth's quip on Coleridge: "*Eternal activity without action*."

What is the difference between *activity* and *action* in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Action", in this case, is used to mean activity which is "intentional under some description", to use Davidson's phrase.  The SEP has a nice [article](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/action/) that elaborates the key factors.

Contrarily, activity is simply motion.  In the Southey quote, [St. Vitus's Dance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sydenham%27s_chorea) refers to a neurological disorder which results in bizarre and uncontrolled twitching; Southey is saying that Coleridge's mind is running around frantically without accomplishing anything intentional or meaningful.

Comment: So Cioran says that intention does not exist and we are always acted upon, even as we delusively think we act.

Comment: @Giorgiomastrò:_ That would appear to be the case.  (I have not read this work of Cioran, so I don't know the context of the argument.)

Comment: Cioran's work I cited above is made up of aphorisms. I cited one in full. (To be honest, I translated it from Italian.) So I think we hit the mark. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, action implies outcome, probably a favorable one. If there is a lot of activity without action in one's mind, it means that there is a lot of unproductive thinking and restlessness and frenzy but the thought process has not resulted in any of the possible outcomes such as an articulated thought, a well-formed theory or opinion that influences one's actions or behavior, a tangible creative output such as a book or a poem or music or solution to a mathematical problem, or, peace of mind.